# Please check my proof : $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 + {x \over k} \right) e^{- {x \over k} }$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, infinite-product

I want to prove Weierstrab's Infinite Product for the Gamma function.
(without using theorems about infinite product or more difficult theorems)

By the Euler's limit formula for the Gamma function,

$\displaystyle \begin{eqnarray*} {1 \over \Gamma(x)} &=& \lim_{n \to \infty} { {x(x+1)(x+2) \cdots (x+n) } \over {n^x n!} } \\ &=& \lim_{n \to \infty} x n^{-x} \left( { {1+x} \over {1} } \right) \left( { {2+x} \over {2} } \right) \cdots \left( { {n+x} \over {n} } \right) \\ &=& \lim_{n \to \infty} x n^{-x} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left( 1 + { x \over k } \right) \\ &=& x \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{-x \log{n} } \cdot e^{x \left( {1 \over 1} + {1 \over 2} + \cdots {1 \over n} \right) } \cdot e^{-x \left( {1 \over 1} + {1 \over 2} + \cdots {1 \over n} \right) } \cdot \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left( 1 + { x \over k } \right) \\ &=& x \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{ x \left(  {1 \over 1} + {1 \over 2} + \cdots {1 \over n} - \log{n} \right) } \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left( 1 + { x \over k } \right) e^{- { x \over k} } \end{eqnarray*}$

I was stuck here not knowing whether or not: $\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 + {x \over k} \right) e^{- {x \over k} }$ is convergent.

But I found the following hint: $ \ln \left( 1 + {x \over n} \right) - {x \over n} \sim - {x^2 \over 2n^2}$ for large $n$

$\displaystyle \begin{eqnarray*} \lim_{n \to \infty} {{{x \over n} -
 \ln \left( 1 + {x \over n} \right)} \over {x^2 \over 2n^2}} &=& \lim_{n \to \infty} {{ {1 \over n} - {1 \over n} { 1 \over {1 + {x \over n}}} } \over {x \over n^2}} \\&=& \lim_{n \to \infty} {{ 1 - { 1 \over {1 + {x \over n}}} } \over {x \over n}} \\&=& \lim_{n \to \infty} n {{ {1 + {x \over n}} - 1 } \over x \left( {1 +  {x \over n} } \right)} \\&=& \lim_{n \to \infty} {1 \over {1 +  {x \over n} }} \\&=& 1 \end{eqnarray*}$

so $\displaystyle \exists \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x^2 \over 2n^2} \iff \exists \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{{x \over n} - \ln \left( 1 + {x \over n} \right) \right\} \iff \exists \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 + {x \over k} \right) e^{- {x \over k} } $

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested in convergence but not evaluating the limit, then you don't have to mess with Gamma function at all. Just take log of this product and convert the partial product into a partial sum like
$$\sum_{k=1}^N(\ln(1+\frac xk) - \frac xk)$$
Now can you use the hint you already know and kick start?

Comment: I think I did that already. I feel confused. So am i wrong or not?

Comment: I just wonder $\displaystyle \exists \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x^2 \over 2n^2} \iff \exists \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{{x \over n} - \ln \left( 1 + {x \over n} \right) \right\} \iff \exists \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 + {x \over k} \right) e^{- {x \over k} } $ is true or not

Comment: @RyuDaeSick you are right about the convergence. But even if you do deal with Gamma function you still can't obtain the exact value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the properties of logarithms as follows:
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)e^{-\frac{x}{k}}\\=e^{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ln\left[\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)e^{-\frac{x}{k}}\right]}\\=e^{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ln\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)-\frac{x}{k}}$$
Now you can much more easily determine whether or not the product converges.